# sub report always coming second page of crystal report in visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I designed crystal report like this:
[image]

in this i have a sub report named

> TransactionDetailed

that i given in **ReportFooter** part. while coming records am getting two problems

```
1->sub report heading not coming all pages,,i want to show sub report heading where ever i am getting subreport
2->in first page of my crystal report only showing main report...not getting sub report,,sub report alwayes showing 2 nd page of my crystal reports onwards,,
```

how i can resolve these two issues?

Comment: You need to move the subreport out of the Report Footer.

Comment: were i have to keep  my sub report???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your report is structured is the reason you are not getting correct results. Report Header and Footer should only contain information you want to show ONCE. Page Header and Footer should contain information you want to see on every page (i.e. a logo, legal info in the footer, etc.). Group Header and Footer will show data for the items you have grouped by. The detail section will show all data that pertains to the group. So either group your data and then put the subreport in the Detail section or create a second detail section and put your subreport in there.

Comment: sir i created second details section and i kept my sub report there..but getting wrong result

Comment: What exactly is the subreport supposed to show? Have you tried putting it in the detail section below the other data?

Comment: i just created second detailed section..then i put my sub report ther..i done this only..i have to do any other way??

Comment: Delete the second detail section and put the subreport in the original detail section underneath the fields you already have in there.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you need to restructure your report. What are you trying to show? What is the subreport supposed to show? Put your labels in the Page Header, not in the Report Header. Group your records by Expert(?), leave your details in the Detail section. Put the subreport in the Group Footer.

Comment: my sub reports supposed to show some records..you mean labels is my subreport heading?

Comment: No, the labels are your field headings that are currently in the Report Header.

Comment: in my crystal report currently report headere having some filed,,that i want to show in first page only..that s why i given that fields there,i want to show sub report field header to rest of all pages

Comment: OK, we are clearly not understanding each other. Are you willing to send me the report with saved data so I can modify it for you and show you what I was talking about?

Comment: sir,,how i can send??

Comment: sir i am working on crystal report,,after running i haven't see any option like file

Comment: I have send report file to your id.